# How to proxy an external site in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am trying to make a proxy server that loads external websites under my domain. My goal with this is to let people visit myDomain.com/anyDomain.com and be able to use anyDomain.com with added functionality (injected JS).

I tried using the Request package to get the html of the site and then send it to the response in Express, but this approach messes up the site (relative paths, missing CSS, bad JS requests, etc).

Is there any node package that accomplishes this task? If not, how can I do it myself?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started, it allows you to call fx `http://localhost:6008/www.example.com/hello/world?foo=bar` which would then proxy `http://www.example.com/hello/world?foo=bar` but if you are going to proxy other webpages you are going to hit all sorts of problems.

First of the fact that it might not be legal. I am not aware of the rules round proxying pages and altering them, you should check the laws regarding your specific use-case.

Secondly, since a lot of content on webpages are using absolute urls (especially if the content uses multiple domains for things like CDN and APIs), these resources are still going to point back to the original destination, which might very well cause  quite a few headaches

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    url = require('url'),
    app = express();

app.get('/:host*', function (request, response, next) {

    var proxyurl = url.parse(request.url);
    var path = request.params[0];
    if (!!proxyurl.search) {
        path += proxyurl.search;
    }

    http.get({
        host: request.params.host,
        path: path,
        headers: {}
    }, function(res) {
        var body = '';

        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            response.end(body);
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Got error: ", e);
    });
});

app.listen(6008);
```

Comment: And a third headache: With the above example, all pages are moved to the second path fragments, but since a lot of pages uses root reference like /styles/main.css, these would still point to the domain root, meaning that it would try to proxy http://styles/main.css. You could avoid this by letting *.yourdomain.com point to the application, and then in the request resolve the sub domain as the domain, fx www.example.com.yourdomain.com/something?really=cool

Comment: Is there any Node module that makes a request to a website an returns the html adapted for replaying? Like pywb in Python but for node. Morten, thank you for the response!

Comment: That is the same thing as above with the exception that you cache the response along with the initial url (first parameter in http.get). Then you can at check at the start of the app.get if you already have that response and then reissue it.

You can also add custom hostname parameter override so a request to 20141203.www.example.com.yourdomain.com/ would fetch the cached version from the 3th December 2014 of www.example.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not legal, so disclaimer: DONT USE THIS CODE.

The following is a very hacky example of how you could do this by using cookies to track the proxied host for any relative urls.

Basically anytime the url path matches `/*.com/*` we set run regex on it and set a cookie `proxy_host` to just whatever matches `*.com`. If the url path does not match that, we check if the cookie `proxy_host` has been set. If it does, we tack the url path onto the cookie `proxy_host` and proxy that url.

```
var app = require('express')();
var request = require('request');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var HOST_RE = /([^/]+\.com)/;

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(function(req, res) {
  // Check if the url matches *.domain/www.somehost.com/*
  if (HOST_RE.test(req.path)) {
    // get a match for the host only, no paths
    var proxyHost = HOST_RE.exec(req.path)[0];
    // clean the path of the host, so that we can proxy the exact
    // page the user requested
    var path = req.path.replace(proxyHost, '');

    // We have to cache the body in this instance because before we
    // send the proxied response, we need to set our cookie `proxy_host`
    var body = '';
    return request.get('http://' + proxyHost + path)
      .on('data', function(data) {
        body += data;
      })
      .on('end', function() {
        res.cookie('proxy_host', proxyHost);
        res.end(body);
      });
  }

  // Url does not match *.domain/www.somehost.com/*
  // most likely a relative url. If we have the `proxy_host`
  // cookie set, just proxy `http://` + proxy_host + `req.path`
  if (req.cookies && req.cookies.proxy_host) {
    return request.get('http://' + req.cookies.proxy_host + req.path).pipe(res);
  }

  // otherwise 404
  res.status(404).end();
});

app.listen(8000);
```